# solr DIH how to index nested docs from mongoDB

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud, dataimporthandler

I am using DIH for indexding the docs from solr to mongo , my data is like below

> { "_id" : "processedSKU_ID-1", "clientName" : "client1",
>   "searchQueryAnalysisObj" : [ { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 1",
>   "searchKeywordScore" : 1.8000000000000003 }, { "searchKeyword" :
>   "iphone 2", "searchKeywordScore" : 5.400000000000001 }, {
>   "searchKeyword" : "iphone 3", "searchKeywordScore" :
>   1.8000000000000003 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 4", "searchKeywordScore" : 0.9000000000000001 } ], "_class" :
>   "com.unilog.model.MainClickStreamData" }

I want to get each searchKeyword and searchKeywordScore and put it into the solr like

> "searchKeyword_1" : "iphone 1","searchKeywordScore_1" :
>   1.8000000000000003 searchKeyword_2" :"iphone 2", "searchKeywordScore_2" : 5.400000000000001 "searchKeyword_3" : "iphone
>   3", "searchKeywordScore_3" :1.8000000000000003  ...........

searchKeyword and searchKeywordScore are dynamic field in my searchIndex so I can push as many searchKeyword and searchKeywordScore I want

along with the id and client name  . ID and client name I am able to index successfully , but the problem is I am not able to index searchQueryAnalysisObj which is arrylist of objects .

I am doing something like this

> ```
>   <entity name="thisg"
>        processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
>          query=""
>          collection="clickStreamProcessed"   
>          datasource="MyMongo"
>          transformer="script:hello">
>
>
>           <field name="clientName" column="clientName" /> 
>           <field name="id" column="_id" />
>
>    </entity>
>    </document>
> ```
>
> > <   ![CDATA[ 
> >          function hello(row) { 
> >          if(row.get('searchQueryAnalysisObj') !== null)
> >            {  var a = row.get('searchQueryAnalysisObj');
> >               for ( var key in a.searchQueryAnalysisObj )
> >                 {
> >                row.put("cat",row.get("_class").toString());
> >                 var num = key +1 ;
> >                var fieldName1 ="searchKeyword" + num;
> >                var fieldName2 = "searchKeywordScore" +  num;
> >                 row.put(fieldName1, a.searchQueryAnalysisObj[key]["searchKeyword"]);
> >           row.put(fieldName2,  a.searchQueryAnalysisObj[key]["searchKeywordScore"]);
> >         }    }
> >
> > return row;
> >
> > } ]]>

could anyone help me where I am doing wrong ?